# Populate Spinner with JSON

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have found this wonderful JSON Parsing [tutorial](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html) for Android and since i am fairly new to this area, i would like to ask how can i populate a spinner with the given data. When the user clicks on the name, the rest of them will load up and then again when the user selects one, it must stay active. Any help will be much appriciated!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // we will using AsyncTask during parsing
        new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
    }

    // you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // set your json string url here
        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String firstname = c.getString("firstname");
                    String lastname = c.getString("lastname");
                    String username = c.getString("username");

                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname
                            + ", lastname: " + lastname
                            + ", username: " + username);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner uses a list object to serve the data. So you should have a backing list to your Spinner object.

Before your for loop, do the following:

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And inside your for loop, add the names to this list:

```
//I'm assuming you are going to display only the first name
namesList.add(firstName);
```

Then create an ArrayAdapter object that binds the list to the Spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, namesList);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your help but the real solution lies the following pice of code which needs to be added in the OnPostExecute():

```js
Spinner yourSpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<YourActivityNAme>.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, namesList);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

create list from json  such this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(json element);
list.add(json element);
list.add(json element);


ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```